# Dump XML string from SoapVar

Tags: php, soap

Is it possible in a way or another to output the corresponding XML string from a `SoapVar`?

For instance:

```php
class Security {
    public $UsernameToken;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->UsernameToken = new UsernameToken();
    }
}

class UsernameToken {
    public $Username = 'foo';
    public $Password = 'bar';
};

$soapVar = new \SoapVar(
    new Security(),
    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT
);
```

From the above variable `$soapVar`, for test purpose, I'd like to get the following raw string:

```xml
<Security>
    <UsernameToken>
        <Username>foo</Username>
        <Password>bar</Password>
    </UsernameToken>
</Security>
```

Comment: Have a look at (SimpleXMLElement )[http://php.net/simplexml]. Read a little about how it works, search for some topics using that. As a hint for you; If you build the object properly you can just call a method ->asXml() and it will return you the desired result. If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: To keep it short and simple: you can 't do it directly by using SoapVar objects. The easiest way would be switching on tracing for the soap client instance and getting the xml via `$client->__getLastRequest()` oder `$client->__getLastResponse()`. These two methods will give you the last sent request and response as xml string.